# OSX go (lang) QML static compile failing due to version difference

Tags: macos, qt, go, qml, static-libraries

I am trying to statically compile a go application using Qt and run it on a computer without Go or Qt installed.

At the top of my main.go I have:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -static -L/Users/$USER/Qt/5.7.0_static_osx/lib -lgb
//go:generate genqrc ui
```

I have static compiled my application using:

```
go generate && go build -a -installsuffix cgo
```

The `go generate` compiles the .qml files into the binary while as I understand it `go build -a -installsuffix cgo` statically compiles all the `.go` and `.a` files from Qt.

I am using `go version go1.8 darwin/amd64` and I have `5.7.0_static_osx` Qt in my `/Users/$USER/Qt` folder and in the `/lib` folder I have all the `.a` files

I am using OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Now the issue is when I move it to another mac I get the error:

```
​/Users/$USER/Downloads/PACKAGED.app/Contents/Resources
AppSettings.plist
MainMenu.nib
appIcon.icns
PACKAGEDAPP
script
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /Users/$USER/Downloads/PACKAGED.app/Contents/Resources/./encryptoclient
  Reason: Incompatible library version: encryptoclient requires version 5.7.0 or later, but QtWidgets provides version 5.4.0
/Users/$USER/Downloads/PACKAGED.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 5:  9987 Trace/BPT trap: 5       ./encryptoclient
```

Which makes me think that Qt wasn't statically compiled, is this so? And if so, what do I need to do to compile properly?

P.S (FYI) Its in a `.app` because I have wrapped it in a [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) app to make moving and running on other computer an easy 'double-click' off the USB stick

Comment: You need a static Qt build. Get the source, configure and build.

Comment: Isn't that what I've done with: `/Users/$USER/Qt/5.7.0_static_osx/lib` described above? I thought that was the static Qt build (that I then followed the build instructions for)